# С# Реализация CompareTo у Tuple

Tags: c#, интерфейс, полиморфизм, tuple, compare

вопрос следующий - почему класс Tuple реализует интерфейс IComparable, но такой код не компилируется:

```
var a = new Tuple<int, bool>(5, false);
var b = new Tuple<int, bool>(5, false);
var c = a.CompareTo(b);
```

Comment: Явная реализация интерфейса? Ну т.е. вот так скомпилируется: `((IComparable)a).CompareTo(b)` https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.tuple-2.system-icomparable-compareto?view=net-6.0#system-tuple-2-system-icomparable-compareto(system-object)

Answer (score 0):

Ответ найден - спасибо Андрею из комментариев.
Для сравнения Tuple, используя CompareTo(), необходимо произвести апкаст к интерфейсу IComparable

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]